# Accessing FirstPersonController script from another to change values doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im trying to make a stamina system for a prototype game im making, having completed it i see no reason as to why it shouldn't work, however it isn't. I suspect its not actually accessing the script and getting the components when im calling for it, hence the title. I wont include the FPS script code, its the standard one from unity and as far as i can tell, isn't needed here. Do let me know otherwise. Below is the code, with what i thought should be a working Stamina system. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Marked as solved, nothing wrong with anything but me, problem was a typo

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;

public class PlayerVitals : MonoBehaviour
{

private float vital = 0;

public Slider healthSlider;
public int maxHealth;
public int healthFallRate;

public Slider thirstSlider;
public int maxThirst;
public int thirstFallRate;

public Slider staminaSlider;
public int maxStamina;
private int staminaFallRate;
public int staminaFallMult;
private int staminaRegainRate;
public int staminaRegainMult;

private CharacterController charController;
private FirstPersonController playerController;



public DeathMenu deathMenu;
public GameObject FPSController;
public Camera Meep;

void Sart()
{
    //sets max value of slider to whatever we set as the max health, thirst etc
    healthSlider.maxValue = maxHealth;
    healthSlider.value = maxHealth;

    thirstSlider.maxValue = maxThirst;
    thirstSlider.value = maxThirst;

    staminaSlider.maxValue = maxStamina;
    staminaSlider.value = maxStamina;

    staminaFallRate = 1;
    staminaRegainRate = 1;


    // call them here in the script so we dont need to write it out everytime
    charController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    playerController = GetComponent<FirstPersonController>();


    Meep.enabled = false;
}
void Update()
{
    //health fall
    if (thirstSlider.value <= 0)
    {
        healthSlider.value -= Time.deltaTime / healthFallRate * 2;

    }

    if (healthSlider.value <=0)
    {
        CharacterDeath();
    }




    //Thirst
    if (thirstSlider.value >= 0)
    {
        thirstSlider.value -= Time.deltaTime / thirstFallRate;
    }

    else if (thirstSlider.value <= 0)
    {
        thirstSlider.value = 0;
    }

    else if (thirstSlider.value >= maxThirst)
    {
        thirstSlider.value = maxThirst;
    }

    //stamina

    if(charController.velocity.magnitude > 0 && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        staminaSlider.value -= Time.deltaTime / staminaFallRate * staminaFallMult;
    }
    else
    {
        staminaSlider.value += Time.deltaTime / staminaRegainRate * staminaRegainMult;
    }

    if (staminaSlider.value >= maxStamina)
    {
        staminaSlider.value = maxStamina;
    }
    else if (staminaSlider.value <= 0) { //if the stamina ever reaches zero, we want the run speed to equal the walk speed
        staminaSlider.value = 0;
        playerController.m_RunSpeed = playerController.m_WalkSpeed;
    }


    //currently can only walk, even after regen, below fixes that, ever above zero, we want it to be our new normal runspeed
    else if (staminaSlider.value >= 0)
    {
        playerController.m_RunSpeed = playerController.m_RunSpeedNorm;
    }
}

void CharacterDeath()
{
    // DIE DIE DIE - Reaper main 2028
   deathMenu.ToggleEndMenu (vital);
   FPSController.SetActive(false);
   Meep.enabled = true;
   Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;

}

}
```

Comment: @Ryolu oh my god, i cant believe i missed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typed `void Sart()` instead of `Start()`

Comment: I feel so stupid, thank you regardless! Should i delete the thread lol?

Comment: @AdamSteele Typos are a common mistake. Always remember to use breakpoints to check if certain things are running. You could either remove it or accept this as the answer, as long as the question is not left open in that sense